# Find a set $A$ such that for any set $X$ there exists $X \cong \text{Hom}_\text{set}(A, X)$

Tags: category-theory

Find a set $A$ such that for any set $X$ is an isomorphism between X and $\text{Hom}_\text{set}(A, X)$.

Really having some trouble here, could someone bother to explain?

Comment: I took the liberty of Latex-izing your question (and changing B to X, which I'm sure you intended). If you press edit, you can see how this works.

Comment: new to the latex i'll do my best to use it in the future but thank you

Comment: It's not LaTeX; it's [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Incidentally, (in answer to a question from a deleted comment thread), you can typeset ${}^{B}A$ by `${}^{B}A$` (and more generally, for anything on this site rendered in MathJax, you can see how it was typeset by right-clicking -> Show Math As -> TeX Commands).

Answer (score 7):

For finite sets, the cardinality of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(A,B)$ is $|B|^{|A|}$. If this is in bijection with $B$, then $|B|^{|A|}$ should be equal to $|B|$. We can guess $A = \{*\}$ is a singleton, and indeed for a singleton $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(\{*\}, X) \cong X$ via $f \mapsto f(*)$.

Comment: i used that fact and concluded that A is any set containing n elements where n is a natural number but i have no clue whether that is correct or not

Comment: also i need to learn the tags :( my apologies

Comment: That's not correct. If $|B| = 2$ and $|A| = 3$, then $|B|^{|A|} = 8$, so $\text{Hom}_{Set}(A,B)$ can't be put in bijection with $B$.

Comment: I simply can't wrap my head around a set that follows this property

Comment: The set containing exactly one element.

Comment: @lancelot: Exactly!

Comment: Once again thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $a\in A$ you can decide where to map $a$ inside $X$... so at least you have one map for every $x\in X$ already. Now move to another $a'\in A$...

Answer (score 1):

you can try with $A=\left\{\emptyset\right\}$, a singleton, $Hom_{SET}(A,X) = X$

Comment: $A=\left\{\emptyset\right\}$ doesn't work but $|A|$ = 1 does.

Comment: Sorry, I denote for $\{\emptyset\}$ a set that have only one element, the empty set. in set category, Every singleton is a terminal object. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets)

Comment: on that note, is the cardinality of the empty set still $1$?

Comment: Alright thanks a lot people. This took me way too long to register